# Having trouble with importing packages in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, package

Our professor gave us a code to work with floating points but it's not compiling.

```
package numeric;

import java.math.*;

public class Floating {
  public static double fl(double x) {
    BigDecimal decX = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(x));
    int r = decX.scale();
    decX = decX.movePointRight(r);
    String intX = decX.toBigInteger().abs().toString();
    int l = intX.length();
    decX = decX.movePointLeft(l);
    decX = decX.setScale(digits, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    decX = decX.movePointLeft(r - l);
    return decX.doubleValue();
  }

  public static void setDigits(int nDigits) {
    digits = nDigits;
  }

  public static int getDigits(int nDigits) {
    return digits;
  }

  static int digits = 16;

  public static double Absolut(double x, double y) {
    return Math.abs(x-y);
  }  

}
```

But when I try the code

```
import numeric.Floating;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x = 123.0456785;
    System.out.println("The number " + x);

    for (int m = 17; m > 0; m--) {
      System.out.println("with  " + m + " significant digits");
      Floating.setDigits(m);
      System.out.println(Floating.fl(x));   
    }

    Floating.setDigits(3);
    double x1 = Floating.fl(100), x2 = Floating.fl(.1);
    System.out.println(x1 + " + " + x2 + " = " + Floating.fl(x1 + x2));
    System.out.println(133 + " + " + 0.921 + " = " + Floating.fl(133+0.921));
    Floating.setDigits(5);
  }
}
```

it says that the package numeric doesn't exist and it cannot access Floating. Is there something wrong with the code?

I have other codes that I need to work with floating points but none of them are working because of this problem.

Comment: Can you provide your directory structure?

Comment: There is something missing in the Test code. There are not enough ending brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes in the default package cannot import those in packages. Move `Test` into `numeric`

```
package numeric;

public class Test {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just needs a couple minor modifications:

- Add *package numeric* to the top of class **Test**.
- Add the 2 missing close brackets to the end of class **Floating**.

Then to run:

- Put classes in directory called *numeric*.
- From the directory below that, run *javac numeric/*.java*.
- Then from that same directory, run *java numeric.Test*.